# nunit TestContext throws NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, resharper

I have the following code:

```
[TestFixture]
public class LexicalTests
{
    [Test]
    public void LexicalTest1()
    {
        TestContext.CurrentContext.TestDirectory;
    }
}
```

`CurrentContext` throws an exception while attempting to get `TestDirectory` or `WorkingDirectory` property.

How can I solve this problem?

P.S.: On my home PC tests work perfectly (without strange exceptions).

Comment: i've seen that there are some similar questions on stackoverflow, but i cant find the answer.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that behaviour. What version of NUnit are you using? How are you running the tests? Do you have any other libraries linked that might also use TestContext as an object name? Do other unit tests run correctly? Can you post the exact code of a failing unit test?

Comment: i use nunit 2.6.2 with Resharper Unit Testing UI...
i found that test passed when i user nunit.exe

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5363635/nunit-testcontext-currentcontext-null-reference-exception

Comment: That's strange because I used the Resharper Test Runner with NUnit 2.6.2 and it worked for me. I am using Resharper 7, which version are you using? My passing code just wraps this line: Assert.IsNotNull(TestContext.CurrentContext.TestDirectory);

Comment: you test code correct - similar code throws exception om my machine.
i've change Resharper 7 default Test Runner with Nunit's implementation and it works fine.

Comment: Are you saying you had to change the NUnit version setting in ReSharper options? Resharper->Options->Tools->NUnit->Run tests with specified NUnit installation?

Comment: yes, i change default Resharper NUnit test runner with my specified installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that some applications that offer the functionality to run NUnit unit tests have a problem with the TestContext class.

The test in class below should pass:

```
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace UnitTests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class UnitTests
    {
        [Test]
        public void CurrentContextTest()
        {
            Assert.IsNotNull(TestContext.CurrentContext);
            Assert.IsNotNull(TestContext.CurrentContext.TestDirectory);
            Assert.IsNotNull(TestContext.CurrentContext.WorkDirectory);
        }
    }
}
```

If the test doesn't pass then, as Dmitry wrote in his comment above, change the NUnit version in the ReSharper menu. From within Visual Studio, go to ReSharper -> Options -> Tools -> NUnit. Click the Specified NUnit installation radio button and ensure that a folder with nunit.core.dll, nunit.core.interfaces.dll and nunit.util.dll is specified. An error will be displayed if the listed files cannot be found.

[image]

Once the NUnit version has been changed, re-run the test and it should pass.